# How to swap the QGraphicsScene from a QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, pyqt

`QGraphicsView` is often hooked up to a `QGraphicsScene`.  What if I want to swap that `QGraphicsScene` for a new one?  How can I accomplish this?  Doing it right now is just drawing over the old one.

Answer (score 0):

To swap the scene just call your view's `setScene()` again with a different `QGraphicsScene` object.

Comment: I'm currently doing this and it draws the new scene overtop of the old scene.  In my example, it's just some lines and rectangles, so tihs is obvious.  It does repaint it though, just not clearing it beforehand.

Comment: Can you post the complete code surrounding setScene() ? There must be a problem somewhere else, I do this in my own code and the setScene() call suffices, the scenes dont't overlap.